# object that may die anytime pointed by several objects

Tags: c++

In my game there are a lot of object of class Foo that interact with each other. A static method of the class Foo update all the object, using a container in order to track the created objects.

My problem is that a Foo object could kill another object, other instances of Foo don't know about this horrible event and they could use the dead object (deleted) anyway, thus giving an error.

I have some ideas to avoid pointer to deleted object, but I don't think they are suitable.

1) A kind of smart pointer that checks for null object.

probably this is the worse idea, I didn't not see anywhere something like this. I could create a pointer which, when delete is called, delete the pointed Foo object and then gives false when converted to Boolean (so it's possible to know if it's possible to call method on it).

2) Each Foo object doesn't track other object with a pointer but with an ID.

then the object gets a pointer to another Foo object with a static method of Foo class ( as I said Foo class has a container that tracks all the instances).
It would work also in a multithreaded environment with simple modifications, but it may be really expansive, each object searches another one in the container during each frame.

3) Each Foo object tracks objects that have a pointer to it. 
The object, when killed (deleted), calls a method of the other objects. Then these object erase any pointer to the deleted object. There are other classes, too. So this isn't really object oriented.

I actually think there is an easy solution that I can't find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially all these objects share ownership of this killable object.  The strongest assurance you can give them is that it won't be deleted out from under them.  You can accomplish that by giving each one a `boost::shared_ptr`.  Notifying all the objects when it dies would allow them to drop their reference.  You can use `boost::signals` to accomplish that.  I would try for this first.

If you can't do that, then you could have them store a `boost::weak_ptr` and when their call to `boost::weak_ptr::lock` failed, they would know it was dead.